как изменить чужой Pull Request будучи меинтейнером?
Я являюсь меинтейнером репозетория, другой человек, контрибьютор, создал PR впервые, я хочу помочь человеку и мне нужно внести свои изменения. На github есть возможность разрешать меинтейнеру вносить изменения. Но описания как это работает нету. Как это сделать?

Сторонние контрибьюторы создают пулл реквесты из форка репозитория. Форк существует на аккаунте контрибьютора. Вам по сути нужно внести изменения в форк. Для того, чтобы вы могли это сделать, автор форка в настройках своего форка добавить вас в collaborators.
